# How to read the contents of a .lua script file?

Tags: encryption, lua

I have a .lua file from an old 2000s game. I tried opening it with Hex editors, and it gives me the header of "LuaP"? Trying to open it in Notepad does give me a few rows of readable text, but the rest of it is garbled characters.

Link to screenshot: https://ibb.co/k41LPgM

Is this Lua file encrypted? And if so, what do I use to decrypt it? And if it's not, then what is a more appropriate tool to use to read the contents of the Lua file?

Comment: It is a Lua 5.0 bytecode.  You need a Lua 5.0 decompiler to see the code.

Comment: See: [LuaTools](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTools) for bytecode decompilers.